# Put JRadioButtons in new rows in ButtonGroup?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jradiobutton, buttongroup

Is there a way to put JRadioButtons on new lines in ButtonGroups? I don't mean 1 button on every line but for example 2 buttons on one line and 2 buttons on the next but each in the same group like this for example:

```
o Button one      o Button two
o Button three    o Button four
```

all in one group and in one panel centered.

Comment: yes. That can be done with a layout. The position of the Button's is not related to the ButtonGroup. The ButtonGroup is simply logical.

Comment: @Dando18 so can you add multiple panels within a ButtonGroup?

Comment: @Dando18  I realize now that ButtonGroup is not a component and now understand what you mean when you say it's "logic." Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the radio buttons in a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout` and in the sametime add `JRadioButtons` to a `ButtonGroup` as well.

Comment: Thank you, I initially thought that the ButtonGroup was a component. My mistake.